# Laravel 5.6. Get first unique row for each unique column key (desc and example are much neater)

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have such a table (simplified version) for logging history of the order:

`order_id (NOT unique) | created_at | message`

It contains such records

```
1 | 2018-03-01 | Message #1
2 | 2018-03-02 | Message #2
2 | 2018-03-03 | Message #3
1 | 2018-03-04 | Message #4
```

How should I query my `OrderAttempt` model to receive **one unique record for each** `order_id`

```
2 | 2018-03-01 | Message #3
1 | 2018-03-01 | Message #4
```

I'm ready to provide a better explanation/more details if needed.

Comment: You want the record with the latest `created_at` date per `order_id`?

Comment: I want recordS with the latest `created_at` date per `order_id`.

Comment: One per `order_id`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes.

Comment: Can there be multiple records with the same date for one `order_id`?

Comment: No. Actually, it's a DateTime column. I've abridged for the simplicity's sake. So `created_at` will be unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168007/discussion-between-d-r-and-jonas-staudenmeir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with my client by querying by max id. For now it works and suits his needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$join = OrderAttempt::select('order_id')->selectRaw('MAX(created_at) created_at')  
    ->groupBy('order_id');
$sql = '(' . $join->toSql() . ') latest';
OrderAttempt::join(DB::raw($sql), function($join) {
    $join->on('order_attempts.order_id', 'latest.order_id')
        ->on('order_attempts.created_at', 'latest.created_at');
})->get();
```

Comment: Staudnenmeir 

As far as I get, you idea is to select rows with max `created_at` and treat it like ID. Am I right?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not `SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "order_attempts_log" LINE 1: ...order_attempt_log" group by "order_id") latest on "order_att... ^ (SQL: select * from "order_attempt_log" inner join (select "order_id", MAX(created_at) created_at from "order_attempt_log" group by "order_id") latest on "order_attempts_log"."order_id" = "latest"."order_id" and "order_attempts_log"."created_at" = "latest"."created_at")`

Comment: Also, have you taken into account, that per `order_id` `created_at` is unique, but throughout the system it's **not**.

Comment: Here is the SQL implementation, that works:



WITH summary AS (
    SELECT order_attempt_log.id,
           order_attempt_log.order_id,
           order_attempt_log.created_at,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_attempt_log.order_id
                                 ORDER BY order_attempt_log.created_at DESC) AS rk
      FROM order_attempt_log)
SELECT s.*
  FROM summary s
 WHERE s.rk = 1

Comment: Please replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` and post the result.

Comment: For this query it's only relevant that `created_at` is unique per `order_id`.

Comment: I've contacted to my client and we have solved this issue by querying max id, cause it's incremental. For now this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$orders = OrderAttempt::select('order_id', 'created_at', 'message')->groupBy('order_id')-> sortBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.